# Update and checking at the same time

Tags: sql-server

I have table as follows

```
CatID| Total_Amount | Amount_paying |IsCompleted
-----|--------------|---------------|------------
CA01 |  2000        |    1700       |  0
```

In this table I have to check if Total_Amount and amount_paying is same or not?
Where total_amount is fixed and amount_paying will get maximize after each insert statement.

So If I insert a record

```
    CatID| Total_Amount | Amount_paying |IsCompleted
    -----|--------------|---------------|------------
    CA01 |  2000        |    1700       |  0
    CA01 | 2000         |    300        |  1
```

Here I am paying 300 , so Total_Amount  = Amount_Paying and IsCompleted=1

```
UPDATE tbl
        SET is_completed = CASE WHEN SUM(amount_paying) = Total_Amount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        WHERE tbl.branch_id =@branchid AND CatID=@catid
```

giving `An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.`

Comment: You mean `IF SUM(amount_paying) = 2000 THEN 1 ELSE 0`? Yourr question is not clear, what will happen if insert another row the `SUM(amount_paying)` will be > 2000

Comment: sum(amount_paying)>200 ? true:false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database engine allows the same target table within the `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE tbl
SET IsCompleted = IF((SELECT SUM(Amount_paying) FROM tbl WHERE CatID = 'CA01') >= Total_Amount, 1, 0)
WHERE CatID = 'CA01';
```

But for example, with MySQL you'll get `Query Error: Error: ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED`.

So, below should work:

```sql
UPDATE tbl AS t
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    CatID, 
    SUM(Amount_paying) AS totalAP
  FROM tbl 
  WHERE CatID = 'CA01'
  GROUP BY CatID
) AS t2 ON (t2.CatID = t.CatID)
SET t.IsCompleted = IF(t2.totalAP >= t.Total_Amount, 1, 0)
WHERE t.CatID = 'CA01';
```

Here is a **[demo fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nNgus1UXibcuvL8rnda3pM/0)**.

*Note: In your own example, you're attempting to set `is_completed`. It should be `IsCompleted` according to your table.*